# XDocument write specific XElement in a single line

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml, xelement

I am writing an XML file using `XDocument`. I want to make adjustments to the file layout. Let me explain, here is an extract of the generated file:

```
<ROOTELEMENT>
  <CHILDELEMENT>
    <INFO1>Test a 1</INFO1>
    <INFO2>Test a 2</INFO2>
  </CHILDELEMENT>
  <CHILDELEMENT>
    <INFO1>Test b 1</INFO1>
    <INFO2>Test b 2</INFO2>
  </CHILDELEMENT>
<ROOTELEMENT>
```

I want my file to look like this instead :

```
<ROOTELEMENT>
  <CHILDELEMENT><INFO1>Test a 1</INFO1><INFO2>Test a 2</INFO2></CHILDELEMENT>
  <CHILDELEMENT><INFO1>Test b 1</INFO1><INFO2>Test b 2</INFO2></CHILDELEMENT>
</ROOTELEMENT>
```

Here is my code:

```
var myDoc = new XDocument(new XElement("ROOTELEMENT",
                                    new XElement("CHILDELEMENT",
                                        new XElement("INFO1", "Test a 1"),
                                        new XElement("INFO2", "Test a 2")),
                                    new XElement("CHILDELEMENT",
                                        new XElement("INFO1", "Test b 1"),
                                        new XElement("INFO2", "Test b 2"))));

myDoc.Save("Test.xml");
```

Comment: Is it really matter? Looks like a formatting issue mostly

Comment: Yes it's a formatting issue. I am replacing another application written in another language and I want the output to be exactly as it was before I come along with my new application.

Comment: I mean, the indentation of the XML doesn't really matter lmao. Any halfway decent XML parser will ignore it, I'm not even sure if there's something that does not

Comment: To my client, it does. I'm guessing to save memory and still keep the file readable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you create an indented XML string from an XDocument in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374654/how-do-you-create-an-indented-xml-string-from-an-xdocument-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

Formatting of XML output is controlled by [`XmlWriter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwriter) not `XElement` or `XDocument`, so if you need precise control of formatting you will need to create your own writer by subclassing one of the implementations of `XmlWriter`, specifically [`XmlTextWriter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmltextwriter) whose [`Formatting`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmltextwriter.formatting?view=net-5.0#System_Xml_XmlTextWriter_Formatting) property is mutable and can be changed during writing.

For instance, here is a version that disables indentation when the element depth exceeds 1:

```
public class CustomFormattingXmlTextWriter : XmlTextWriter
{
    readonly Stack<Formatting> stack = new Stack<Formatting>();

    public CustomFormattingXmlTextWriter(TextWriter writer, int indentDepth) : base(writer) 
    { 
        this.Formatting = Formatting.Indented; 
        this.IndentDepth = indentDepth;
    }
    
    int IndentDepth { get; }

    void OnElementStarted(string localName, string ns)
    {
        stack.Push(Formatting);
        // You could e.g. modify the logic here to check to see whether localName == CHILDELEMENT
        // if (localName == "CHILDELEMENT")
        if (stack.Count == IndentDepth+1)
            Formatting = Formatting.None;
    }

    void OnElementEnded()
    {
        var old = stack.Pop();
        if (old != Formatting)
            Formatting = old;
    }

    public override void WriteStartElement(string prefix, string localName, string ns)
    {
        base.WriteStartElement(prefix, localName, ns);
        OnElementStarted(localName, ns);
    }

    public override void WriteEndElement()
    {
        base.WriteEndElement();
        OnElementEnded();
    }
    
    public override void WriteFullEndElement()
    {
        base.WriteEndElement();
        OnElementEnded();
    }
}

public static partial class XNodeExtensions
{
    public static void SaveWithCustomFormatting(this XDocument doc, string filename, int indentDepth)
    {
        using (var textWriter = new StreamWriter(filename))
        using (var writer = new CustomFormattingXmlTextWriter(textWriter, indentDepth))
        {
            doc.Save(writer);
        }
    }
}
```

Using it, you can do:

```
myDoc.SaveWithCustomFormatting(fileName, 1);
```

which outputs, as required:

```xml
<ROOTELEMENT>
  <CHILDELEMENT><INFO1>Test a 1</INFO1><INFO2>Test a 2</INFO2></CHILDELEMENT>
  <CHILDELEMENT><INFO1>Test b 1</INFO1><INFO2>Test b 2</INFO2></CHILDELEMENT>
</ROOTELEMENT>
```

Notes:

- You can modify the logic in `CustomFormattingXmlTextWriter.OnElementStarted()` to disable the formatting using any criteria you desire such as checking to see whether the incoming `localName` is `CHILDELEMENT`.
- `XmlTextWriter` is deprecated in favor of `XmlWriter` -- but the latter does not have a mutable `Formatting` property.  If you must needs use `XmlWriter` you might look at *[Is there a way to serialize multiple XElements onto the same line?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5698215/3744182)*.

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xUrwr3).